# if Condition returning false inside callback function

Tags: jquery

I have got two `div` containers where I can drag and drop videos between these two containers.

Before dropping a `div`, I am checking whether this Video already exists inside the second `div` container or not.

If it doesn't exists inside the second `div` container then only I am dropping it or else doing nothing.

For this I am using the callback function stop to check this way

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
  var video_id = $(ui.item).attr('video-id')
  var checker = checkifVideoExists(video_id);

  if (checker) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function checkifVideoExists(videoid) {
  var flag = false;
  $("#excersisesinpac .portlet").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('video-id') === "" + videoid + "") {
      flag = true;
    } else {
      flag = false;
    }
  });
  return flag;
}
```

But unfortunately this condition is working only for when Video6 is dragged , but not for Video5 (Drag videos into second container only)

https://jsfiddle.net/Lphf43wd/9/

Comment: Your every `.portlet` will be assumed as last `.portlet`. When you find that `flag = true` return from callback.

Comment: thanks for your input but even when i removed the else conditions also its giving me problem .

Comment: Remove `else` part will not help. You need to `return false` inside `if`

Comment: (Could you please help me with a sample fiddle )

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working for 2 reasons:

1. You are not breaking `$.each` when you found that you already have that element in list. Need to apply `return false;` inside `$.each` to `break` it (`return true` to continue).
2. You always have `.portlet` inside list, because drag-n-drop will move temporary that element to your list.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lphf43wd/12/)

Comment: Thnaks but  If i move the video2 to FIRST Container  and then move it back to the Second Container the code getting failed